# R package cosinor predict with newdata gave error message

Tags: r

I fit the cosinor model with data "vitamind" in the package, then I tried to predict based on cosinor.fit using my newdata. Although I used the same variable names in my newdata as those in 'vitamind', I got error message when I ran `predict(cosinor.fit, newdata = mydata)`:

```
cosinor.fit <- cosinor.lm(Y ~ time(time) + X + amp.acro(X), data = vitamind)
summary(cosinor.fit)
predict(cosinor.fit) # worked fine
predict(cosinor.fit, newdata = mydata) # did not work, error message as below 
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'rrr' not found
```

I tested using its own data as newdata, it gave same error message

```
predict(cosinor.fit, newdata = vitamind) # did not work either
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'rrr' not found
```

Can anyone give me some tips? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform your time variable in the new data:

```
newdat <- vitamind
period  <- 12 #the default in cosinor.lm
newdat$rrr <- cos(2 * pi * newdat[, "time"]/period)
newdat$sss <- sin(2 * pi * newdat[, "time"]/period)

predict(fit, newdata = newdat) #works

#test if result is the same (within numerical precision)
all(abs(predict(fit) - predict(fit, newdata = newdat)) < 1e-10)
#[1] TRUE
```

Arguably, the predict method should do this for you. You could contact the package maintainer with an improvement suggestion.